# Loop through range, find value in separate worksheet, copy values and return and paste

Tags: excel, foreach, macros, vba

I have a recorded macro that I want to make more intelligent and maintenance free. The macro is very specific in that cell addresses and values are hard-coded. If the list of values changes, then the macro code has to be edited. Not a problem for me, but future users will likely not have the knowledge or inclination to do it.

I think a loop would be the best solution, but am not certain how to proceed.

Here's the current version of the code:

```
    '======= APPROVED
    Sheets("Worksheet").Visible = True  -- Unhide the "Worksheet" tab
    Sheets("Worksheet").Select
    Range("B8").Select                  -- go to cell B8
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Approved" -- type "Approved"

'C9755
'Expense and Lease Current Year
    Range("B2").Select                  -- Go to cell for search value
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "C9755"    -- Type in "C9755" (first item)
    Range("I1:T1").Select               -- Copy the total in the range
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Summary by Component").Select -- Go back to other tab
    Range("C9").Select                    -- This is where "C9755" is
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
'Capital Depreciation
    Sheets("Worksheet").Select    -- Now go back and do the same for Capital
    Range("I2:T2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
    Range("C35").Select   -- This is where "C9755" Capital is
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Picture of flow:
[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh6Gp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use cells(1,1) instead of range("A1"). Your code will be faster and easier to read. You can test it with this simple code by changing the ' of line:

```
Sub test()
Dim starttime As Double
Dim s As String
Dim i As Long

starttime = Timer

    For i = 1 To 10 ^ 5
    s = Range("A1").Value
    's = Cells(1, 1).Value
    Next i

MsgBox Timer - starttime

End Sub
```

Other than that, if your code is working, leave it like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give more details on "If the list of values changes, then the macro code has to be edited"

What's the changes in the list of value? Change of cells value or range? What's the criteria?

You're problem seems simple to manage with loops. You have a simple explanation of how it works here : http://www.excel-pratique.com/en/vba/loops.php

***EDIT***

You might have to make some changes as I'm not sure of the exact thing you want your code to do but try with something like this :

```
Sub LoopWhile()

i = 9

While Sheets("Summary by Component").Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""

    Sheets("Summary by Component").Cells(i, 2).Copy

    Sheets("Worksheet").Select
    Cells(2, 2).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Range(Cells(1, 9), Cells(1, 20)).Copy
    Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
    Cells(35, 3).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    i = i + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @celapointe, thank you for the link. I will have a look at that.

Comment: The list of values I want to use starts in cell B9 of a sheet called "Summary by Component". What the code should do is: 1. Read the value in cell B9; 2. Go to a sheet called "Worksheet" and put that value in cell B2.; 3. Copy the values returned in cells I1 through T1; 4. Return to "Summary by Component" and paste the values in. 5. Repeat the process by going to the next cell. Continue until a blank row is found, then stop.

Comment: Here is what I have now. Considerably shorter than what I had before, but still think it can be tighter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with. I'm sure it could be tighter, so any suggestions greatly appreciated:

```
' Turn off screen updating so you don't see windows jumping around
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Worksheet").Visible = True
    Sheets("Summary by Component").Select

    'Expense and Lease - Approved
    Dim LSearchRowA As Integer
    Dim LCopyToRowSummA As Integer
    LSearchRowA = 9
    LCopyToRowSummA = 9

    'Capital - Approved
    Dim LSearchRowB As Integer
    Dim LCopyToRowSummB As Integer
    LSearchRowB = 35
    LCopyToRowSummB = 35

    'Expense and Lease - Potential Buy
    Dim LSearchRowC As Integer
    Dim LCopyToRowSummC As Integer
    LSearchRowC = 62
    LCopyToRowSummC = 62

    'Capital - Potential Buy
    Dim LSearchRowD As Integer
    Dim LCopyToRowSummD As Integer
    LSearchRowD = 88
    LCopyToRowSummD = 88


'======= Start components updates =======
'Wend through Approved Expense and Lease
    While Len(Range("P" & CStr(LSearchRowA)).Value) > 0

        'Select row in "Summary by Component" to copy
        Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRowA)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste selection into Component field on "Worksheet" tab
        Sheets("Worksheet").Select
        Range("B2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("B8").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Approved"

        'Copy Expense and Lease Totals and copy to "Summary by Component" tab
        Range("I1:T1").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
        Range("C" & CStr(LCopyToRowSummA)).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        LSearchRowA = LSearchRowA + 1
        LCopyToRowSummA = LCopyToRowSummA + 1

       'Go back to "Summary by Component" tab to continue
        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
    Wend

'Wend through Approved Capital
    While Len(Range("P" & CStr(LSearchRowB)).Value) > 0

        'Select row in "Summary by Component" to copy
        Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRowB)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste selection into Component field on "Worksheet" tab
        Sheets("Worksheet").Select
        Range("B2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        'Copy Expense and Lease Totals and copy to "Summary by Component" tab
        Range("I2:T2").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
        Range("C" & CStr(LCopyToRowSummB)).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        LSearchRowB = LSearchRowB + 1
        LCopyToRowSummB = LCopyToRowSummB + 1


       'Go back to "Summary by Component" tab to continue
        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
    Wend

'Wend through Potential Buy Expense and Lease
    While Len(Range("P" & CStr(LSearchRowC)).Value) > 0

        'Select row in "Summary by Component" to copy
        Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRowC)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste selection into Component field on "Worksheet" tab
        Sheets("Worksheet").Select
        Range("B2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("B8").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Potential Buy"

        'Copy Expense and Lease Totals and copy to "Summary by Component" tab
        Range("I1:T1").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
        Range("C" & CStr(LCopyToRowSummC)).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        LSearchRowC = LSearchRowC + 1
        LCopyToRowSummC = LCopyToRowSummC + 1


       'Go back to "Summary by Component" tab to continue
        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
    Wend

'Wend through Potential Buy Capital
    While Len(Range("P" & CStr(LSearchRowD)).Value) > 0

        'Select row in "Summary by Component" to copy
        Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRowD)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste selection into Component field on "Worksheet" tab
        Sheets("Worksheet").Select
        Range("B2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        'Copy Expense and Lease Totals and copy to "Summary by Component" tab
        Range("I2:T2").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
        Range("C" & CStr(LCopyToRowSummD)).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        LSearchRowD = LSearchRowD + 1
        LCopyToRowSummD = LCopyToRowSummD + 1


       'Go back to "Summary by Component" tab to continue
        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
    Wend

'======= End component updates =======

    Sheets("Worksheet").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B8").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Worksheet").Visible = False

    Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
    Range("A1").Select

'======= Clean up and go home =======
'Turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Prompt the user that the updates are complete
MsgBox "The update is complete."
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you assistance, @celapointe. This is the final code:

```
    Sheets("Summary by Component").Select

    'Expense and Lease - Approved
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 9                       

    'Capital - Approved
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 35               

    'Expense and Lease - Potential Buy
    Dim k As Integer
    k = 62

    'Capital - Potential Buy
    Dim m As Integer
    m = 88

'Wend through Approved Expense and Lease
    While Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""

        Cells(i, 2).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Worksheet").Select

        Cells(2, 2).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Cells(8, 2).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Approved"

        Range(Cells(1, 9), Cells(1, 20)).Select ' Select I1:T1
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
        Cells(i, 3).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


        i = i + 1

        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
    Wend

'Wend through Approved Capital
    While Cells(j, 2).Value > 0

        Cells(j, 2).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Worksheet").Select
        Cells(2, 2).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(2, 20)).Select ' Select I2:T2
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
        Cells(j, 3).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        j = j + 1

        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
    Wend

'Wend through Potential Buy Expense and Lease
    While Cells(k, 2).Value > 0

         Cells(k, 2).Select
         Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Worksheet").Select
        Cells(2, 2).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Cells(8, 2).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Potential Buy"

        Range(Cells(1, 9), Cells(1, 20)).Select ' Select I1:T1
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
        Cells(k, 3).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        k = k + 1

       Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
    Wend

'Wend through Potential Buy Capital
    While Cells(m, 2).Value > 0

        Cells(m, 2).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Worksheet").Select
        Cells(2, 2).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(2, 20)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
        Cells(m, 3).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        m = m + 1

        Sheets("Summary by Component").Select
    Wend
```